# check if Redactor initialised

Tags: jquery, redactor, redactor.js

I am using [Redactor WYSIWYG editor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) for my content edit. How can I check if redactor has been initialised on certain element ? I am currently checking if element has a class name `redactor-editor`, but I guess there must be better way?

```
$('.btn-edit-content').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!$($(this).attr('href')).hasClass('redactor-editor'))
        $($(this).attr('href')).redactor({
            toolbarFixedTopOffset: 95,
            plugins: ['table']
        });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

According to their api doc, you can do something like this

```
$('.btn-edit-content').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

     if( $.data($($(this).attr('href'))[0], 'redactor') === undefined) {

         $($(this).attr('href')).redactor({
             toolbarFixedTopOffset: 95,
             plugins: ['table']
         });

     }
});
```

[Look at their doc for more help](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api/core/)

Hope it's gonna help you

Comment: I was looking for something like this yes, but when I am calling `$('#el').redactor('core.getEditor')` I get this strange error in console: `TypeError: h is undefined`. I think this can not be called before Redactor is actually initialised on the plugin...

Comment: You're right, look at my edit, it should works now.
Take note that here we check only if the editor is defined, I don't know if this condition will work if you have used the destroy method previously

Comment: Try by replacing `$(this).attr('href')` with your identifier. And are you sure your error comes from redactor? Try to init redactor with 0 config too. This error has no reason to live more, we do no job over the plugin, we're just checking if 'redactor' is set on the element.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet found a better way, so I'm checking whether Redactor is initialized or not this way (the snippet is in coffeescript):

```
$('.redactor').each ->
  $editor = $(this).siblings('.redactor-editor')
  $(this).redactor() unless $editor.length
```

context: I have several textareas having class `.redactor` on 1 page and at some point some of them lose Redactor's initialization. If I just call `.redactor()` for all textareas at once then previously initialized Redactors get duplicated.